# In MATLAB how can I write out a multidimensional array as a string that looks like a raw numpy array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, numpy, encode, toml

**The Goal**

*(Forgive me for length of this, it's mostly background and detail.)*

I'm contributing to a TOML encoder/decoder for MATLAB and I'm working with numerical arrays right now. I want to input (and then be able to write out) the numerical array in the same format. This format is the nested square-bracket format that is used by *numpy.array*. For example, to make multi-dimensional arrays in numpy:

*The following is in python, just to be clear. It is a useful example though my work is in MATLAB.*

*2D arrays*

```py
>> x = np.array([1,2])
>> x
array([1, 2])

>> x = np.array([[1],[2]])
>> x
array([[1],
       [2]])
```

*3D array*

```py
>> x = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])
>> x
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])
```

*4D array*

```py
>> x = np.array([[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]],[[[9,10],[11,12]],[[13,14],[15,16]]]])
>> x
array([[[[ 1,  2],
         [ 3,  4]],

        [[ 5,  6],
         [ 7,  8]]],


       [[[ 9, 10],
         [11, 12]],

        [[13, 14],
         [15, 16]]]])
```

The input is a logical construction of the dimensions by nested brackets. Turns out this works pretty well with the TOML array structure. I can already successfully parse and decode any size/any dimension numeric array with this format from TOML to MATLAB numerical array data type.

*Now, I want to encode that MATLAB numerical array back into this char/string structure to write back out to TOML (or whatever string).*

So I have the following 4D array in MATLAB (same 4D array as with numpy):

```matlab
>> x = permute(reshape([1:16],2,2,2,2),[2,1,3,4])
x(:,:,1,1) =
     1     2
     3     4
x(:,:,2,1) =
     5     6
     7     8
x(:,:,1,2) =
     9    10
    11    12
x(:,:,2,2) =
    13    14
    15    16
```

And I want to turn that into a string that has the same format as the 4D numpy input (with some function named *bracketarray* or something):

```matlab
>> str = bracketarray(x)
str =
    '[[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]],[[[9,10],[11,12]],[[13,14],[15,16]]]]'
```

I can then write out the string to a file.

**EDIT:** I should add, that the function `numpy.array2string()` basically does exactly what I want, though it adds some other whitespace characters. But I can't use that as part of the solution, though it is basically the functionality I'm looking for.

**The Problem**

Here's my problem. I have successfully solved this problem for up to 3 dimensions using the **following** function, but ***I cannot for the life of me figure out how to extend it to N-dimensions***. I feel like it's an issue of the right kind of counting for each dimension, making sure to not skip any and to nest the brackets correctly.

*Current bracketarray.m that works up to 3D*

```matlab
function out = bracketarray(in, internal)
    in_size = size(in);
    in_dims = ndims(in);

    % if array has only 2 dimensions, create the string
    if in_dims == 2
        storage = cell(in_size(1), 1);
        for jj = 1:in_size(1)
            storage{jj} = strcat('[', strjoin(split(num2str(in(jj, :)))', ','), ']');
        end
        if exist('internal', 'var') || in_size(1) > 1 || (in_size(1) == 1 && in_dims >= 3)
            out = {strcat('[', strjoin(storage, ','), ']')};
        else
            out = storage;
        end
        return
        % if array has more than 2 dimensions, recursively send planes of 2 dimensions for encoding
    else
        out = cell(in_size(end), 1);
        for ii = 1:in_size(end) %<--- this doesn't track dimensions or counts of them
            out(ii) = bracketarray(in(:,:,ii), 'internal'); %<--- this is limited to 3 dimensions atm. and out(indexing) need help
        end
    end
    % bracket the final bit together
    if in_size(1) > 1 || (in_size(1) == 1 && in_dims >= 3)
        out = {strcat('[', strjoin(out, ','), ']')};
    end
end
```

Help me Obi-wan Kenobis, y'all are my only hope!

**EDIT 2:** *Added test suite below and modified current code a bit.*

**Test Suite**

Here is a test suite to use to see if the output is what it should be. Basically just copy and paste it into the MATLAB command window. For my current posted code, they all return `true` except the ones more than 3D. My current code outputs as a cell. If your solution output differently (like a string), then you'll have to remove the curly brackets from the test suite.

```matlab
isequal(bracketarray(ones(1,1)), {'[1]'})
isequal(bracketarray(ones(2,1)), {'[[1],[1]]'})
isequal(bracketarray(ones(1,2)), {'[1,1]'})
isequal(bracketarray(ones(2,2)), {'[[1,1],[1,1]]'})
isequal(bracketarray(ones(3,2)), {'[[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]]'})
isequal(bracketarray(ones(2,3)), {'[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]'})
isequal(bracketarray(ones(1,1,2)), {'[[[1]],[[1]]]'})
isequal(bracketarray(ones(2,1,2)), {'[[[1],[1]],[[1],[1]]]'})
isequal(bracketarray(ones(1,2,2)), {'[[[1,1]],[[1,1]]]'})
isequal(bracketarray(ones(2,2,2)), {'[[[1,1],[1,1]],[[1,1],[1,1]]]'})
isequal(bracketarray(ones(1,1,1,2)), {'[[[[1]]],[[[1]]]]'})
isequal(bracketarray(ones(2,1,1,2)), {'[[[[1],[1]]],[[[1],[1]]]]'})
isequal(bracketarray(ones(1,2,1,2)), {'[[[[1,1]]],[[[1,1]]]]'})
isequal(bracketarray(ones(1,1,2,2)), {'[[[[1]],[[1]]],[[[1]],[[1]]]]'})
isequal(bracketarray(ones(2,1,2,2)), {'[[[[1],[1]],[[1],[1]]],[[[1],[1]],[[1],[1]]]]'})
isequal(bracketarray(ones(1,2,2,2)), {'[[[[1,1]],[[1,1]]],[[[1,1]],[[1,1]]]]'})
isequal(bracketarray(ones(2,2,2,2)), {'[[[[1,1],[1,1]],[[1,1],[1,1]]],[[[1,1],[1,1]],[[1,1],[1,1]]]]'})
isequal(bracketarray(permute(reshape([1:16],2,2,2,2),[2,1,3,4])), {'[[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]],[[[9,10],[11,12]],[[13,14],[15,16]]]]'})
isequal(bracketarray(ones(1,1,1,1,2)), {'[[[[[1]]]],[[[[1]]]]]'})
```

Comment: MATLAB orders its axes in the opposite way.  The trailing ones are the outer most.  The `x(:,:,1,1) =...` reflects that.  Also MATLAB was originally just 2d.  The `numpy` display is an extension of the Python list display, with bracket nesting reflecting the leading-outermost axes order.

Comment: Seems to me that the simplest thing is to save the MATLAB matrices to a file (old-style), and use `scipy.io.loadmat` to load them as `numpy` arrays.  You may still have to deal with the switch in axes order (and `order='F'`), but display will be a lot easier.  But watch out - `array2string` uses ellipsis when the array gets too big.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for your comments, but the python portion is just a description. I don't want to use it (I can't because I can't have it as a dependency) and it doesn't really affect the outcome/solution.

Comment: No forgiveness necessary! Super-detailed questions like this are easier to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier to just loop and use join. Your test cases pass.

```
function out = bracketarray_matlabbit(in)

    out = permute(in, [2 1 3:ndims(in)]);
    out = string(out);

    dimsToCat = ndims(out);
    if iscolumn(out)
       dimsToCat = dimsToCat-1; 
    end

    for i = 1:dimsToCat
       out = "[" + join(out, ",", i) + "]"; 
    end
end
```

This also seems to be faster than the route you were pursing:

```
>> x = permute(reshape([1:16],2,2,2,2),[2,1,3,4]);

>> tic; for i = 1:1e4; bracketarray_matlabbit(x); end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.187955 seconds.

>> tic; for i = 1:1e4; bracketarray_cris_luengo(x); end; toc
Elapsed time is 5.859952 seconds.
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. It follows the conceptual process exactly; collecting all the (original) columns first, then rows, then planes, etc.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The recursive function is almost complete. What is missing is a way to index the last dimension. There are several ways to do this, the neatest, I find, is as follows:

```matlab
n = ndims(x);
index = cell(n-1, 1);
index(:) = {':'};
y = x(index{:}, ii);
```

It's a little tricky at first, but this is what happens: `index` is a set of `n-1` strings `':'`. `index{:}` is a comma-separated list of these strings. When we index `x(index{:},ii)` we actually do `x(:,:,:,ii)` (if `n` is 4).

The completed recursive function is:

```matlab
function out = bracketarray(in)
n = ndims(in);
if n == 2
   % Fill in your n==2 code here
else
   % if array has more than 2 dimensions, recursively send planes of 2 dimensions for encoding
   index = cell(n-1, 1);
   index(:) = {':'};
   storage = cell(size(in, n), 1);
   for ii = 1:size(in, n)
      storage(ii) = bracketarray(in(index{:}, ii)); % last dimension automatically removed
   end
end
out = { strcat('[', strjoin(storage, ','), ']') };
```

Note that I have preallocated the `storage` cell array, to prevent it from being resized in every loop iteration. You should do the same in your 2D case code. Preallocating is important in MATLAB for performance reasons, and the MATLAB Editor should warm you about this too.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I've tried your function and it works sometimes and it doesn't others. I added to my post a Test Suite to run to check a number of examples. For your function, you'll have to either remove the curly brackets in the test suite or you'll have to make the main output a cell. Your function fails in cases where the second dimension is 1 and also when the array is a column or row vector. I've incorporated some of your suggestions and and trying to grok your main algorithm.

Comment: Looking at it, I think the reason it fails when the 2nd dimension (the columns) is size 1 is because of the mat2str. It doesn't wrap it in brackets when it's a single element.

Comment: @GaetaWoo: I explicitly made the output a string because I don’t see the purpose of a cell array with a single element. If `mat2str` is not suitable, put back your original code for the 2D case. I thought the question was how to deal with arbitrary number of dimensions and I’ve shown how to do that.

Comment: Point taken on the output type. I'm still working out the system you've got for dealing with the dimensions. My concern though is that it brakes cases that were not previously broken, basically that it doesn't work generally. Though it does work for the specific example I had given which you proved. I'm grateful for the time you've taken looking into this.

Comment: @GaetaWoo: The `n>2` case isn’t broken. I’ve removed the broken part, you have working code for that bit. Good luck!